# Old ALSA application and PulseAudio

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

I have an very old application, from repository - it's `soundmodem` (for amateur AX.25 radio packets).

I'm using Linux Mint 17 with default sound driver, it's *PulseAudio*. Options in application configuration:

- **soundcard**: */dev/dsp*, */dev/dsp1*, ...
- **alsa**: *hw:0,0*, *plughw:0,0*, *hw:1,0*, ...

And checkbox for *Half duplex* and *Capture channel* (mono / right / left).

I can't make this application works together with Chrome or other application that plays sound to mixer. I tried to run this with `padsp` (on stduser or root) and set device to `/dev/dsp` (what works in other apps), but i got error:

```
sm[10925]: audio: starting "/dev/dsp"
sm[10925]: audio: forcing half duplex mode
sm[10925]: audio: Error, cannot set nonblocking mode
```

Any ideas how to run this?

**EDIT**: ALSA options:

[image: ALSA options]

Comment: Did you try ALSA device `default`?

Comment: @CL. look at updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct ALSA device name to run on PulseAudio would be `default`.

Apparently, `soundmodem` does not allow to use this device name.
You have to [disable PulseAudio temporarily](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8425/how-to-temporarily-disable-pulseaudio) and let that program use the ALSA device directly.